# iPhone X is showing a visual defect when pushing a ViewController

Tags: ios, iphone, uiviewcontroller, uinavigationcontroller, uisplitviewcontroller

I am seeing a visual defect (half gray bar / dark bar) at the bottom when I push a ViewController when using a iPhone X.

**This is easily reproduced when you create a project using the Master-Detail App template. (File-> New-> Project-> Master-Detail App). Then run the app on the iPhone X simulator.**

I'm running Xcode 9.2 - the visual defect shows up in the iPhone X simulator and on a real iPhone X iOS 11.2.2 This visual defect does not show up on the iPhone 7 or iPhone 8.

Seems that the issue stems from the fact that the view being pushed on is inside of a UINavigationController. However, this is needed to support multitasking on an iPad.

Does anyone have a work around to get rid of this visual defect?

[image: Sample of the defect]
[image: Storyboard]

Comment: Could you paste some code or/and screenshot of a storyline,...

Comment: @MarkoZadravec I've added the storyboard diagram as clarification on the flow. However, this is easily reproduced when you create a project using the Master-Detail App template.  Like... File-> New-> Project-> Master-Detail App. Then run the app on the iPhone X simulator. Seems that the issue stems from the fact that the view being pushed on is inside of a UINavigationController. However, this is needed to support multitasking on an iPad.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
self.navigationController?.navigationBar.isTranslucent = true
```

Comment: I did try to set
    `self.navigationController?.toolbar.isTranslucent = true`
    `self.navigationController?.navigationBar.isTranslucent = true`
On both navigation controllers.
        
This does improve the visual defect. There remains a jump in the toolbar area after the push is finished. However, it looks much better now. I'll try to apply this to the original app I found the issue in. Thanks!